# Error in Databricks : It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, multiprocess

I am trying to run following code in databricks std cluster.

```
from multiprocess import Pool
p = Pool(4)
sql_scripts = ["select * from t1","select * from t2"]
def transform(sql_script):
    spark.sql(sql_script)
    return 0
p.map(transform,sql_scripts)
```

***It is giving me error*** :

- **It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a
  broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only
  be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more
  information, see SPARK-5063**

I want to submit multiple sql scripts to the transform function that just does spark.sql() over script. Idea is to have sql_scripts list from outside configs and it would be much complex and may contain custom logic. Please help me achieve same in databricks.

Note:  I don't wish to use custom solutions like calling it from adf in parallel or using databricks job workflows, delta live framework since this logic is gonna get submited by custom function written outside databricks .

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a collection of SQL scripts, but it needs to a be a single-threaded loop on the driver; not spawning multiple processes with ‘multiprocess’.

Each SQL script will be executed across the whole Spark cluster.

Comment: I want to do it in parallel, sql scripts are independent.

Comment: If you really wanted to you could directly use Spark submit for the jobs. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Is it possible to do spark-submit within databricks notebook. Or do i need to call api for doing so

Comment: I do not know if you can.  But you can certainly use the Databricks APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This is demo code that is working in my case.

```
def tranformer(sql_script):
  #   spark.sql(sql_script)
  print(f"\nrunning {sql_script}\n")
  print(f"\nrunnin finished for {sql_script}")
  return 0
sql_scripts = ["table1","table2"]  
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=3)
    res = pool.map_async(tranformer, sql_scripts)
    res.wait()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Following are the results running it several times to prove parallel runs.
transformer function can have any logic.

1)
[image: run-1]

2)
[image: run-2]